# Using Expression.Dynamic to generate a converter for value types

Tags: c#, dynamic

Part of the data layer for my application is a converter cache similar to `System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`, used in Linq-to-Data. The premise of the cache for all known types I generate a simple converter and cache it. The converter casts the object as T, or in the case of `DBNull.Value`, returns `default(T)`  (unlike `UnboxT` which throws an exception on non-nullable value types.) The reason I can't use UnboxT is that our developers don't like checking for DBNull before assigning a value from the datarow and they just want it done for them.
We also have a factory to generate helper delegate that instantiates objects off of a DataRow, and it'd be annoying to add logic in the delegate. 
i.e. it generates something like this this::

```
datarow =>
    new MyObject()
    {
        property1 = DBConverterCache<TProperty1>.Converter(datarow[columnName1]),
        property2 = DBConverterCache<TProperty2>.Converter(datarow[columnName2]),
        /*etc...*/

    };
```

Even more so, I have another annoyance. Objects in the object layer may not match correctly to ones in the database. This is a problem because you can't unbox things to the "wrong" type. I.e. the property in the object layer is an `Int32`, the column in the DB is an `Int64`. To fix this I have for the struct IConvertibles the converter basically does this::

```
value => value == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (value as IConvertible).To<Type*>(null);
```

`* in the case of Nullable<T> or Enum it casts to underlying type, then casts up to T`

This is ugly as we have to use reflection to generate the call to `ToType`, which relies on the assumption that they will never expand the IConvertible interface to add more objects that are convertible. It's a hack but it avoids boxing the return type. Which a method like  IConvertible.ToType does.

of course this works just as well:

```
value => value == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T)(value as dynamic);
```

Maybe even better, as I don't have to specialize the call based on the type I can just make that my default converter. The only issue I haven't a clue as to how to use Expression.Dynamic, and I can't create an expression that takes dynamic as a parameter. I suppose I could just bind it to a static method or the above lambda expression, but I'd like to do everything as expression trees, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I got this to work, with some good old reflector.

```
    public static Converter<Object, T> CreateDynamicConverter<T>()
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object)); 
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Converter<object, T>>(
            Expression.Condition(
                Expression.Equal(
                    param,
                    Expression.Constant(
                        DBNull.Value
                    )
                ),
                Expression.Default(
                    typeof(T)
                ),
                Expression.Dynamic(
                    Binder.Convert(
                        CSharpBinderFlags.ConvertExplicit, 
                        typeof(T), 
                        typeof(MyApplicationNameHere)
                    ), 
                    typeof(T), 
                    param
                )
            ),
            param
        );
        return expression.Compile();
    }
```

Seems to be working just fine.